# How to indicate the merge tool on command line when running `hg histedit`

Tags: mercurial

How can one indicate the merge tool on the command line when running `hg histedit`? It doesn't seem to support the `--tool` flag like `hg merge` and `hg rebase` do.

Answer (score 1):

A few commands that handle merge conflicts don't seem to have the --tool option. We probably should fix that.

In the meantime, you can use `--config ui.merge=studgeeks_preferred_merge_tool` as a global option for any command to use whatever merge tool you might like.

Answer (score 0):

1. Nohow
2. Histedit not merge in hg-terms, but *combine sequential changes* into one (if needed after fold)

Just imagine such test-repo history

```
>hg log --style compact
7[tip]   dd4d044125d6   2020-09-23 18:58 +0500   lazybadger
  Renaming

6   1c11e58879be   2020-09-23 18:56 +0500   lazybadger
  Expanding b

5   4eecc2e00de0   2020-09-23 18:54 +0500   lazybadger
  Fix casing in a

4   c4fb7f8f9d6a   2020-09-23 18:53 +0500   lazybadger
  End of replacing nums by words in a

3   f153e48d474b   2020-09-23 18:53 +0500   lazybadger
  Start of replacing nums by words in a

2   020cf4853caf   2020-09-23 18:50 +0500   lazybadger
  Added file b

1   1cbe55623ca6   2020-09-23 18:48 +0500   lazybadger
  Added string to a

0   2248df06d3de   2020-09-23 18:47 +0500   lazybadger
  initial commit
```

and I want to get more "clean history" in it

**Step 1**

join r3 and r4 - `hg histedit f153`

```
mess f153e48d474b 3 Replacing nums by words in a
fold c4fb7f8f9d6a 4 End of replacing nums by words in a
pick 4eecc2e00de0 5 Fix casing in a
pick 1c11e58879be 6 Expanding b
pick dd4d044125d6 7 Renaming
```

Result

```
>hg log --style compact
6[tip]   4cc2af840d4c   2020-09-23 18:58 +0500   lazybadger
  Renaming

5   ad1f49e75863   2020-09-23 18:56 +0500   lazybadger
  Expanding b

4   6a1e1cfb767a   2020-09-23 18:54 +0500   lazybadger
  Fix casing in a

3   089e21dda924   2020-09-23 18:53 +0500   lazybadger
  Replacing nums by words in a

2   020cf4853caf   2020-09-23 18:50 +0500   lazybadger
  Added file b

1   1cbe55623ca6   2020-09-23 18:48 +0500   lazybadger
  Added string to a

0   2248df06d3de   2020-09-23 18:47 +0500   lazybadger
  initial commit
```

Aggregated diff (sorry for russian date, I'm too lazy to change it)

```
>hg diff -c 3
diff -r 020cf4853caf -r 089e21dda924 a.txt
--- a/a.txt    Ср сен 23 18:50:50 2020 +0500
+++ b/a.txt    Ср сен 23 18:53:43 2020 +0500
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-Line 1
-Line 2
-Line 3
-Line 4
+Line one
+Line two
+Line three
+Line four
```

Step 2

If I'll want now join (new) 3 and 4 I'll do it the same way `>hg histedit 089e`

```
mess 089e21dda924 3 Replacing nums by words in a
roll 6a1e1cfb767a 4 Fix casing in a
pick ad1f49e75863 5 Expanding b
mess 4cc2af840d4c 6 Renaming
```

Result

```
>hg log --style compact
5[tip]   6c9516e6159f   2020-09-23 18:58 +0500   lazybadger
  Renaming files to correct langs

4   dfb843cc3841   2020-09-23 18:56 +0500   lazybadger
  Expanding b

3   ff58feffa9a5   2020-09-23 18:53 +0500   lazybadger
  Replacing nums and proper casing in a

2   020cf4853caf   2020-09-23 18:50 +0500   lazybadger
  Added file b

1   1cbe55623ca6   2020-09-23 18:48 +0500   lazybadger
  Added string to a

0   2248df06d3de   2020-09-23 18:47 +0500   lazybadger
  initial commit
```

And no merges in processes, because I have I source, set of changes, not 2 sources with diverged history